# How to remove context-root from generated swagger

Tags: quarkus

I have am application that has a context-root set (property: quarkus.http.root-path).
Using quarkus-resteasy-reactive-jackson, a resource was created with a @Path annotation.

Now I want to generate OpenAPI documentation for my resource.
As I want to deploy this into a API gateway, **I require a server property with a context root in the swagger**.
I added a server entry using the mp.openapi.servers property.

The problem now appears that when there is a root-path property, the generated swagger resource path includes this root path, e.g.

quarkus.http.root-path=/sample

mp.openapi.servers=http://localhost:8080/sample

Resource annotated with @Path("resource")

It seems that the resource path includes the root-path.
So importing this swagger into the API gateway (or just clicking on the Try button), results in a url of http://localhost:8080/sample/sample/resource being attempted which ofc does not exist.

Is there a way to not to add the root-path to the resource endpoint in swagger? (I tried using mp.openapi.extensions.application-path.disable=true, but this had no effect)

I managed to get past this by doing the following:

1. dont set quarkus.http.root-path
2. quarkus.rest.path=/sample
3. quarkus.http.non-application-root-path=/sample/q
4. mp.openapi.servers=https://localhost:8080/sample

So just want to know if anyone know of a better way of doing this?